# Short URL generator not working in tinycc_client

Tags: javascript, short-url

Tinycc_client is not working. I am trying to generate short URL on the basis of given refer code. It keeps saying me not defined just like the screenshot. There is no error on console.

The output return `[object Object]`

#### script.js

```
    arrjson = {
            "4397242":"3627884"
        }

    var longLink = "";
    var customParam = "";
    function getCustomShortLink() {
        var client = new tinycc_client({
            api_root_url: "https://tinycc.com/tiny/api/3/",
            username: 'mihir',
            api_key: '*******-****-****-****-*******'
        });

        client.set_working_domain("lpts.2.vu");

            for (x in arrjson) {
                longLink += "http://app.nextbee.com/api/refer/"+arrjson[x];
                customParam = x;
                client.shorten(longLink, {"custom_hash": customParam}).then(function (result) {
                     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += result +"<br>";
                });
            }

        }



    getCustomShortLink()
```

#### html:

```
<div id="demo">

</div>  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/tinycc_client.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

It keeps saying that a variable is not defined.

[image: error]

Comment: The `result` is an Object, so when you output it directly as a String, you get `[object Object]`. It contains an `error` field, and you can output `result.urls[0].short_url_with_protocol`. That being said, your piece of code works perfectly for me. That error you get does not make sense, since `api_root_url` is not a variable but an Object property. Try wrapping these properties with quotes, but I don't think it's goint to change anything. PS: that API was poorly made. They have done terrible work on the data structures they return.

Comment: thank you for the correction over object object. The codes working fine now. I successfully generated shorturl. Can you post your answer for object object. I will accept that. that was only the problem.